# Can multiple end cities spawn in Minecraft Bedrock edition (specifically consoles)?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm aware that they can in java, but i haven't really explored the end on console.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can, just like any other version. You might need to look around for a bit, as they are fairly rare.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, they spawn in all versions of Minecraft** starting from 1.9 on Java Edition and 1.0 on Pocket Edition (also known as Bedrock Edition). But, they have a random chance of spawning, even if the worlds use the same seed. This happens because they use a random number generator (RNG), which means that any chance of them appearing is much rarer then other naturally generated structures. Also, they spawn in very far away from the main island, and sometimes thousands of blocks are travelled without luck.